# How to gather config files in a list with Hydra-fb?

Tags: python, fb-hydra

Say I have an abstract class `db` in my code and classes `db1`, `db1`, ... `db1` that inherit from `db`.
My project uses [hydra](https://hydra.cc/) and has this structure:

```
├── my_app.py
├── conf.yaml
└── db
    ├── db1.yaml
    ├── db2.yaml
    └── db3.yaml
```

I need a list of `db` so I would like to get a final configuration file like this :

```yaml
db:
  -
    param1_of_db1: key_1_1
    param2_of_db1: key_1_2
  -
    param1_of_db2: key_2_1
    param2_of_db2: key_2_2
  -
    param1_of_db3: key_3_1
    param2_of_db3: key_3_2
```

so that `db` is a list of params of `db1`, `db2`, `db3`.
In `conf.yaml` file, I imagine something like:

```yaml
defaults:
  - db: [db1, db2, db3]
```

Is there a way to do something like that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are asking for is not supported by Hydra.

1. List composition is not supported, lists are all or nothing during composition.
2. Config groups are mutually exclusive, there is a [feature request](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/499) to relax that.

You can get close to it though (without being able to override the structure from the command line is something like:
config.yaml:

```yaml
defaults:
  - db/db1
  - db/db2
  - db/db3
```

This syntax is documented [here](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/basic/your_first_app/defaults#non-config-group-defaults).

In each db config file you can do something like:

db/db1.yaml:

```yaml
# @pacakge _group_._name_
host: localhost
port: 3306
```

Package overrides are documented [here](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/overriding_packages).

The resulting config would looke like:

```yaml
db:       # from the config group of the corresponding config (path)
  db1:    # from the name of the corresponding config
    host: localhost
    port: 3306
  db2:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Omry, that's really helpful !

Comment: btw do you plan to include list composition in next version of Hydra ?

Comment: No plans, in 99% of the cases the best thing to do is to replace a list with the second list on merge.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it seems like it is supported by Hydra now (since [Hydra 1.1](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.1/patterns/select_multiple_configs_from_config_group/)
): https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/select_multiple_configs_from_config_group/

```
defaults:
  - db:
    - db1
    - db2
    - db3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get pretty close to list merging with the latest hydra/omegaconf

The trick is that dictionaries are composed, so you can compose the config in a dictionary and then use the new `oc.dict.values` interpolation to get the final list.

So in your case it would be something like:

```
defaults:
  - dbs/db1
  - dbs/db2
  - dbs/db3

db: ${oc.dict.values:dbs}
```

Note that I've renamed the "db" package to "dbs". So the final resolved config would look like:

```
dbs:
  db1:    
    host: localhost
    port: 3306
  db2:
    host: localhost
    port: 3307
  db3:
    host: localhost
    port: 3308

db:
  - host: localhost
    port: 3306
  - host: localhost
    port: 3307
  - host: localhost
    port: 3308
```

The keys for the "dbs" package aren't used for anything but I find that it actually makes the config clearer to have them.